# Doctrine 2 Order By Count with join for Symfony 2 Pagerfanta

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm using Symfony2 with Doctrine 2 and i'm creating a Query for the Pagerfanta Bundle for Symfony 2.

The Query is the following:

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('t')
            ->select()
            ->join('t.pois', 'p');
$qb->groupBy('t.id');
$qb->addOrderBy('count(case when p.image = 1 then 1 else null end)', 'DESC');
```

Which will give out the following Query:

```
SELECT t FROM Bundle\Entity\Turn t INNER JOIN t.pois p GROUP BY t.id ORDER BY count(case when p.image = 1 then 1 else null end) DESC
```

I also created a MySQL Query first so i can rebuild it in Doctrine 2 which looks like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM `turn`
LEFT JOIN (
    poi
) ON ( turn.id = poi.turn_id )
GROUP BY turn.id
ORDER BY count( case when poi.image = 1 then 1 else null end) DESC;
```

This native Query works perfectly fine, tested in phpmyadmin.

But the Doctrine 2 Query throwes this exeptions:

```
Twig_Error_Runtime: An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("[Syntax Error] line 0, col 115: Error: Expected end of string, got '('") in Bundle:Admin:showTurnsFiltered.html.twig at line 64.

QueryException: [Syntax Error] line 0, col 115: Error: Expected end of string, got '('
```

What am i doing wrong? Or is the Pagerfanta bundle not able to work with this Query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by adding a column to the `turn` Entity (`count_poi`) and filling it via native SQL.

After that the Query is the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM `turn`
ORDER BY t.count_poi DESC;
```

BUT it's just a workaround, i'm not happy with it, but it works for now